# Build a custom Android ROM for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-2, display, kernel

How to create a custom Android ROM for the Raspberry Pi from scratch? It can be from any source, it does not matter (like aosp, lineage os, resurrection remix, etc), but the system apps must be changed to my custom app.

I am using the 7" official touch screen and a Raspberry Pi, or in other words, I am turning my Raspberry Pi into an Android tablet.

Please help me by giving tutorials on how to build a ROM.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry PI SE. Users of any SE would expect you to do your own homework and ask more specific questions about problems you encounter. Have you tried a Google search? [This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763) may be a good starting point for you.  You may attract more attention on xda forms or the Android SE. Good Luck.